# Gormで1つのカラムに対して複数のユニーク制約をかけたい

Tags: mysql, go, gorm

Gormで1つのカラムに対して複数のユニーク制約をかけたいのですが、

```
type Object struct {
    Z string `gorm:"unique_index:unique_a;unique_index:unique_b"`
    A string `gorm:"unique_index:unique_a"`
    B string `gorm:"unique_index:unique_b"`
}
```

上記のように記述しても、zに制約が適応されません。

どのように記述すれば可能かでしょうか？

Comment: `unique_index:unique_uid,unique_username` と記述することで解決しました。

Answer (score 1):

`unique_index:unique_uid,unique_username` と記述することで解決しました。

<sub>-- この回答は、[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/44744/gorm%E3%81%A71%E3%81%A4%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AB%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0%E3%81%AB%E5%AF%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E8%A4%87%E6%95%B0%E3%81%AE%E3%83%A6%E3%83%8B%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E5%88%B6%E7%B4%84%E3%82%92%E3%81%8B%E3%81%91%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84#comment46358_44744)として投稿されていた質問者さんによる解決法をコミュニティ wiki による回答として再投稿したものです。</sub>